# How to display data with suffix/prefix in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write an SQL Statement that displays details (id, date and cost) of Table_Session. Display sessions that are scheduled in June or costs $14 or less. Cost must be prefixed with "$" and the results must be sorted in descending order.

Ive gotten everything apart from "prefixed with $" How do I do that?

```
SELECT SESSIONID, SESSIONDATE, SESSIONPRICE
FROM SESSIONS
WHERE SESSIONDATE LIKE '%JUN%' 
OR SESSIONPRICE < 14
ORDER BY SESSIONPRICE DESC;
```

is what Ive got. What needs to be added to make prefix or suffixes in sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `CONCAT` function in MySQL to concatenate strings:

```
SELECT SESSIONID,
       SESSIONDATE,
       CONCAT('$', CAST(SESSIONPRICE AS VARCHAR(15))
FROM SESSIONS
WHERE SESSIONDATE LIKE '%JUN%' OR
      SESSIONPRICE < 14
ORDER BY SESSIONPRICE DESC
```

Comment: `SELECT *` isn't what you want here, because that will include the `SESSIONPRICE` column without the `$` prefix.  It is better to list out all columns as I have done.

Comment: i understand, but in a different scenario if I am selecting all, how would I go about this? Would I just have to list all columns out like in this case?

Comment: @RobBor AFAIK, and from what I just searched, there is no syntax in MySQL to do `SELECT *` except.

Comment: Oh, alright then. May I ask why you have cast it as `VARCHAR(15)`? Is it a trivial matter as to the value and datatype?

Comment: @RobBor You don't have to cast it, I just tested and verified that `CONCAT` will work without the cast.  Ideally, `CONCAT` expects two _strings_, not a string and a number, so it is semantically correct to cast the session price to `VARCHAR`.  But if you don't, MySQL appears to handle it for you automatically.

Comment: Oh yeah it does. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SESSIONID, SESSIONDATE, '$' + cast(SESSIONPRICE  as Varchar(15))
FROM SESSIONS
WHERE SESSIONDATE LIKE '%JUN%' 
OR SESSIONPRICE < 14
ORDER BY SESSIONPRICE DESC;
```